# resetting password in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, passwords, reset

i'm new to codeigniter, and i am attempting to create a password reset system
this is my controller:

```
    public function changePassword(){
    if($this->session->userdata('loginuser'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('loginuser');

     $email = $this->session->userdata('email');

     $data['email'] = $email;

     $data['title'] = 'Change my Password | Watch Stop';

     $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
     $this->load->view('watch_stop/vpassword', $data);
     $this->load->view('template/footer');


     }
    else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }
}

public function reset_password(){
    if($this->session->userdata('loginuser'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('loginuser');

     $email = $this->session->userdata('email');

     $data['email'] = $email;


    //validating form
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('old_password','Old Password','trim|required|min_length[5]|md5');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_password','New Password','trim|required|min_length[5]|matches[cnew_password]|md5');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cnew_password','Confirm Password','trim|required||md5');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->changePassword();
        //$this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Failed to update password</div>');

    }else {

        $query=$this->customer_model->change_password();


            $data = array( "main_content" => 'includes/memberadmin/memberadmin_cpass_process',
            "query" => $query
            );
            $this->load->view('includes/memberadmin/template',$data);


    }



     }
    else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }
}
```

this is my model:
function change_password(){

```
     $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->where('email',$this->session->userdata('email'));
    $this->db->where('password',$this->input->post('old_password'));
    $query=$this->db->get('user');   

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
     {
            $row = $query->row();
            if($row->email===$this->session->userdata('email'))
            {
                $data = array(
                  'new_password' => $this->input->post('new_password')
                 );
              $this->db->where('email',$this->session->userdata('email'));
              $this->db->where('new_password',$this->input->post('old_password'));
                   if($this->db->update('user', $data)) 
                   {
                   return "Password Changed Successfully";
                   }else{
                    return "Something Went Wrong, Password Not Changed";
                   }
            }else{
            return "Something Went Wrong, Password Not Changed";
            }


     }else{
        return "Wrong Old Password";
     }
 }
```

When i click on the update button in my reset password page, i am getting the following error for my new password confirmation field: Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Confirm Password.()

please help!

Comment: You have an empty rule in your cnew_password validation, try removing it

Comment: And if you're building a new system or if you're able to ... stop using md5 for password encryption; use password_hash instead and do not encrypt the password in your validation (it's a bad habit)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** there are two pipe signs near **required||md5**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cnew_password','Confirm Password','trim|required||md5');
```

change it to

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cnew_password','Confirm Password','trim|required|md5');
```

---

**2)** changing input to md5 at this stage is not good. 
You have to use `password_hash` function. 
Read More >> http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

---

**3)** You forgot to load model. `$this->load->model('customer_model');`